# Does GNOME Chess upload anything to developers?

Tags: gnome, games

Sorry I'm new to Linux in general.

I'm a bit cautious of installing software from the official repositories as I'm coming from Windows and I'm unsure what's considered safe.

I'm also having a hard time finding any privacy policy for certain software. Right now I'm interested in installing GNOME Chess. I was wondering if this game uploads anything such as user statistics/analytics. Or does this game keep itself offline with no interaction with developers or anything?

Comment: isn't gnome chess just a graphical front-end?

Comment: "I'm a bit cautious of installing software from the official repositories" That's backwards. You should be perfectly comfortable installing software from your distro's official repositories, and extremely cautious of installing software from anywhere else.

Comment: Installing from the official repositories for your distribution is as safe as you're going to *get* -- if you don't trust your distribution not to include backdoors in the software they package for you, you should use a different distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should audit [the source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-chess), or have someone you trust do it for you, and then check that the package you install actually matches the code that you’ve audited. However if you’re willing to take some random stranger’s word for it, I’m confident (from having looked at the source code myself) that GNOME Chess itself doesn’t send anything back to its developers, or to anyone else for that matter.

Since GNOME Chess uses a separate chess engine, you should also look at that; since I don’t know what engine you’re using, I can’t answer for you now.